# What makes having an array of pointers to page table entries better than having an array of page table entries?

Tags: memory, memory-management, operating-system, kernel, paging

Here in [this lecture](https://youtu.be/pW3g_yWMMYk?t=1159), some extreme implementations of a page table are discussed as well as some reasonable ones.

One of the extreme cases was to allocate a flat array that maps every possible virtual address to a physical address.

At the minute `19:19` (which the given link will start at), the lecturer says that he's talking about a flat array of pointers to PTEs. And then mentions that he could've done something even more stupid which is to use an array of actual page table entries.

Why would having an array of pointers to PTEs be better that having an actual array of PTEs?

He is talking about a 32 bit system with an address of 4 bytes, But PTE is also 4 bytes.

Isn't having an array of pointers more wasteful because it'll take double the space (4 bytes for the pointer and 4 for the PTE)?

Also, I believe that allocating a lot of PTEs that're spread across the physical memory would cause fragmentation and will be hard to manage, as opposed to creating just an array of PTEs which will be one chunk of memory that does not need a lot of management.

Why would having an array of pointers be a better case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have many virtual address spaces that are all 4 GiB each; you might find that:

- a large area (e.g. 1 GiB) is used for kernel and needs to be the same in all virtual address spaces. Because this is the same in all virtual address spaces, any modification in this area needs to modify every virtual address space at the same time.
- various areas will be shared by 2 or more virtual address spaces for other reasons - memory mapped files, shared libraries, shared memory, "copy on write" areas caused by "`fork()`", etc.
- some areas will be the same in the same virtual address space (e.g. refer to the same "read only physical page full of zeros" to implement an "allocate on write" strategy)
- a lot of space will be entirely unused (maybe an average of 2 GiB per virtual address space)

For anything that's used in multiple places; a "pointer to PTE" would give you a single PTE that can be modified regardless of how many places the page is used.

For one example; let's say you have a "C standard library" shared by 40 different processes (and included in 40 different virtual address spaces), but part of the library's code is still on disk and the PTE/s for those parts say "not present". When any process needs that part of the shared library you get a page fault (because it's not present yet) and the OS has to fetch the page from disk. In this case "pointer to PTE" means the OS can change one PTE (from "not present" to "present") and doesn't need to figure out how many PTEs need to be updated, then update 40 different PTEs for 40 different virtual address spaces/processes.

> Isn't having an array of pointers more wasteful because it'll take double the space (4 bytes for the pointer and 4 for the PTE)?

Array of pointers to PTEs would waste more space, but it's hard to say how much space (it wouldn't be "double" because lots of PTEs would be used multiple times, and might be closer to 50% more space). Array of PTEs would waste more CPU time (in kernel's code trying to manage everything) instead, and (if you take into account kernel using its own additional data/memory to be able to figure out which pages are shared where) it might actually cost more memory.

However...

They are both relatively awful; and I'd expect that the lecturer is preparing to introduce multi-level paging (where "one pointer to PTE per page" gets replaced with "one pointer to group of PTEs"), which is what most real CPUs use.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, he actually discussed a linked list of PTEs and then introduced the multi-level paging.

Answer (score 1):

An overhead incurs when walking the page tables to find a translation. Every now and then a new paper is published explaining how their implementation is superior. Some suggest [hashing the page tables](http://www.cs.technion.ac.il/%7Edan/papers/hvsr-sigmetrics-2016.pdf). I suggest you don't over think it, understand the principles of walking the page tables and a simple implementation is enough to get a grasp.